# Easing options in jQuery is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-easing

I have tried using easing so many times for education purposes but in vain my trials never succeeded surely I did something wrong but for two days now I could not identify the mistake, so I include here my jQuery function and hoping you will tell me where is the problem.

The result of the attached code is just hiding instead of animating

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#hide').click(
        function()
        {
            $('p').toggle(
            function()
            {
                $('p').animate({'padding':'=+150px'},3000,'swing')
            },
            function()
            {
                $('p').animate({'padding':'=-150px'},3000,'linear')
            }
            );
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: This form of toggle is deprecated in the latest version of jquery

Comment: so what is the substitute for toggle in the new versions.

Comment: can you show the html code you want to associate to your animating process

Comment: <input id='hide' type="submit" value="hide"/>
  <p>Hello world!</p>

Comment: @MohamedSamir See my answer for a toggle substitute.  It appears no simple jquery method has replaced the function `toggle` with form `toggle(func,func)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the call to the deprecated form of `toggle` replacing it with a simple boolean.  Also note that `padding` should be set like `-=150px` instead of `=-150px`.

```
var toggle = true;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#hide').click(
        function()
        {
            if(toggle){
                $('p').animate({'padding':'+=150px'},3000,'swing');
                toggle = false;
            }else{
                $('p').animate({'padding':'-=150px'},3000,'linear');
                toggle = true;
            }
        }
    )
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nBzCL/